# How to use join in SPARK (scala)

Tags: scala, apache-spark

**My text file has this format:**
File:

> ```
> 1|52|3956|337.0
> 1|77|4069|357.8
> 1|7|14|35.2
> 2|3|8895|378.4
> 2|3|4969|915.2
> 2|3|8539|438.3
> 2|78|3025|306.3
> ```

**runnable code**

```
val file = sc.textFile("path")

val filtered = file.filter(line=> (line.split('|')(2)<args(1)) && (line.split('|')(3))>args(2))

val count= filtered.map(line=> (line.split('|')(0),line.split('|')(1))).distinct.countByKey

val sum= filtered.map(line=> (line.split('|')(0),line.split('|')(2).toInt*(line.split('|')(3).toFloat))).reduceByKey((a,b)=>a+b)        

val result= count.join(sum)
```

I tried to join the above two but I got this error:

> value join is not a member of scala.collection.Map[String,Long]

Does anyone knows how to solve this issue?

Comment: add runnable code that shows how "filtered", "count", and "sum" look like.

Comment: Adding some runnable code and the schema will simplify the work required by whoever will answer the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code `count` is of the type `Map[String,Long]` and your `sum` is `RDD[(String, Long)]`. The error you are getting says that there is no `join` defined for `Map[String,Long]` type. So to resolve it you can change your `count` to,

```
val count: RDD[(String, Int)] = filtered.map(line => (line.split('|')(0), line.split('|')(1))).distinct.map(x => (x._1, 1)).reduceByKey(_ + _)
```

Now there `count` is of the type `RDD[(String, Int)]` and you can apply `join` to it as

```
count.join(sum)
```

which will be of the type `RDD[(String, (Int, Long))]`